# Using structural types as "trait argument"

Tags: scala

I'm building my code using traits as modules in a way that I can plug them interchangeably and as needed, something like the following example:

```
trait Module1 { def method1 = "method1" }

trait Module2 { def method2 = "method2" }

abstract class BaseClass {
  def doWork: Unit
}

class ClassImpl extends BaseClass with Module1 with Module2 {
  def doWork: Unit = {
    println(method1)
    println(method2)
  }
}
```

However, some of my modules depend on some configuration variables (user-defined, runtime arguments), something I would pass as constructor parameters if they were classes. As traits do not accept parameters my idea for this was by using structural types:

```
trait Module1 { 
  this: {
    val config1: Int
    val config2: Int
  } =>
  def method1 = s"method1 c1=$config1 c2=$config2"
}

trait Module2 { def method2 = "method2" }

abstract class BaseClass {
  def doWork: Unit
}

case class Config(c1: Int, c2: Int)
class ClassImpl(config: Config) extends BaseClass with Module1 with Module2 {
  protected val config1 = config.c1
  protected val config2 = config.c2
  def doWork: Unit = {
    println(method1)
    println(method2)
  }
}
```

Is it a good strategy for configuring my modules or there is something better?

Answer (score 1):

Structural types involves reflection and are there is a better solution indeed, consider the following example:

```
trait Module[F,S] { this: Config[F,S] =>
  def method = s"method1 c1=$config1 c2=$config2"
}

trait Config[F,S] {
  def config1: F
  def config2: S
}

case class DefaultConfig[T,S](config1: T, config2: S) extends Config[T,S]

case class ConfigCls(c1: Int, c2: Int)
class ClassImpl(config: ConfigCls) extends DefaultConfig(config.c1, config.c2) with Module[Int,Int] {
  def doWork(): Unit = {
    println(method)
  }
}
```

This way you avoid using structural types, doing basically the same thing as in your original post.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It seems a nice approach, but how does it work if  I have different trait-modules, each one with a different set of configuration variables? Do I need to include the union of all these variables in the `Config` trait?

Comment: Well you can define config trait for every module (ModuleA -> ConfigA etc.) than create: `class DefaultConfig(...) extends ConfigA with ConfigB ... with ConfigZ`

Comment: I see, thanks. Another question: in my project, the class "ClassImpl" already extends another class, so how would I make it extend DefaultConfig? Do I have to make the parent class extend DefaultConfig?

Comment: It's a limit to this pattern if you want to use scala method overriding syntactic sugar, i can't imagine clean solution to this right now. You can always override methods manually and not have to extend `DefaultConfig`